# How to use the Web Speech API in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-recognition, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I am wondering if it is possible to run the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html) in node.js? Since node is Javascript based, I was assuming it could be used, but I can't find a way to use it natively in node. Would there be a way to "include" this Web Speech Library in a node.js script to use it?

Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  Who would be speaking to the server? Or are you considering a recorded wav of some sort?

Comment: there is headless chrome now

Answer (score 7):

While you can't use the WebSpeechAPI in Node (as it is a built in browser capability), you can use [Google Cloud Speech](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/speech/0.2.0/speech) or one of the many other cloud recognizers that have Node SDKs.

If you're looking for a super lightweight implementation that handles all of the audio encoding and supports offline hotword detection I would recommend [Sonus](https://github.com/evancohen/sonus).

Disclaimer: this is my project

Answer (score 1):

You can try [WSNR npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wsrn), but it requires running a chrome browser.

Answer (score -3):

**Demo.JS**

```
angular.module('PubNubAngularApp', ["pubnub.angular.service"])
.controller('MySpeechCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, Pubnub) {
  $scope.theText = "Don't just stand there, say something!";
  $scope.dictateIt = function () {
      $scope.theText = "";
      var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
              $scope.theText  += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
          }
        });
      };
      recognition.start();
  };
});
```

**Link to codepen.io demo**

[Here](https://codepen.io/geekstrick/pen/gRdRMw) is the complete package for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it will only work in the browser, whereas the OP was asking how to use the Web Speech API in node.js.